# using beautiful soup to scrape different attribute from string

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have string in this form : `<COREF ID="3" REF="2"> Jacks Smith </COREF>`

I am taking `id`,`ref`, and value that is  `Jacks Smith`

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '<COREF ID="1">Salman</COREF> <COREF ID="2">Khan</COREF> (pronunciation born <COREF ID="3" REF="2">Abdul Rashid Salim Salman Khan</COREF> on 27 December 1965)[3] is an <COREF ID="14">Indian</COREF> film <COREF ID="15">actor</COREF>, <COREF ID="17">producer</COREF>, television <COREF ID="19">presenter</COREF>, and <COREF ID="20">philanthropist</COREF> known for <COREF ID="4" REF="2">his</COREF> Hindi films. <COREF ID="5" REF="2">He</COREF> is the <COREF ID="21">son</COREF> of <COREF ID="16" REF="15">actor</COREF> and screenwriter Salim <COREF ID="6" REF="2">Khan</COREF>. <COREF ID="7" REF="2">Khan</COREF> began <COREF ID="8" REF="2">his</COREF> acting career with <COREF ID="22">Biwi Ho</COREF> To <COREF ID="24">Aisi</COREF> but <COREF ID="18" REF="17">it</COREF> was <COREF ID="9" REF="2">his</COREF> second film <COREF ID="25">Maine Pyar</COREF> <COREF ID="26">Kiya</COREF>(1989), in which <COREF ID="10" REF="2">he</COREF> acted in a lead role, that garnered <COREF ID="11" REF="2">him</COREF> the Filmfare Award for Best Male Debut. <COREF ID="12" REF="2">Khan</COREF> has starred in several commercially successful films, such as <COREF ID="28">Saajan</COREF> (1991), <COREF ID="29">Hum Aapke Hain Koun</COREF>..! (1994), <COREF ID="30">Karan Arjun</COREF> (1995),<COREF ID="31">Judwaa</COREF> (1997), <COREF ID="32">Pyar</COREF> <COREF ID="27" REF="26">Kiya</COREF> To Darna <COREF ID="33">Kya</COREF> (1998), <COREF ID="23" REF="22">Biwi</COREF> No.1 (1999), and Hum Saath <COREF ID="34">Saath Hain</COREF> (1999), having appeared in the highest grossing film nine separate years during <COREF ID="13" REF="2">his</COREF> career, a record that remains unbroken.[4]'
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
#print soup

a = []

for entry in soup.find_all('coref'):
    print entry.name.string  # Issue this prints "coref" rather printing the result like "Salam" for first id
    print entry['id']   
    #a[entry['id']] = entry.name.string  Here I want to create array for ID and it should content corresponding string

for entry in soup.find_all('coref'):
  if entry.has_key('ref'):
    print entry
    print entry['ref']
    #print a[entry['ref']]    printing here refering entity from array a
```

issues:

1. `print entry.name.string` does not give string result
2. Is that correct way to store `id` in array key and assigning the string value
3. give warning `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py:1413: UserWarning: has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr("ref") instead.
   key))`

Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

1. `entry.name` refers to the name of the tag. You should use `entry.get_text()`.
2. You can't insert to a list at arbitrary positions. You should declare `a` as a dict (`a = {}`).
3. As the warning said, the function `entry.has_key` is deprecated and may be removed in the next version. You should replace it with something like `if entry.has_attr('ref'): ...`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there is once issue `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` at `a[int(entry['id'])] = entry.get_text()`

Comment: @user2129623 sorry, I forgot that you can't do that in python (inserting elements to arbitrary positions in a list). I have edited the answer.